Having problems with Langchain and SQLDatabaseToolkit: 'sql_db_list_tables' and others doesn't work
everyone. I'm trying to query a MySQL database using Python and Langchain. However, some features seem to return nothing, while others work. sql_db_list_tables, get,usable_table_names, table_info and others do not work, while other features like sql_db_query work. I've tried the same code with a postgresql database with read and write permissions and I didn´t get this trouble, just worked fine. This MySQL databse just have the read permissions.
Here is the code and de output:
Code:
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase

mysql = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:3306/{db_name}"

database = SQLDatabase.from_uri(mysql, schema="db_freterapid2", view_support=True)
print(database.dialect)
print(database.get_usable_table_names())
print(database.table_info)
database.run("SHOW FULL TABLES FROM db_freterapid2;")

Result:
mysql
[]


"[(bytearray(b'aereo_esg'), bytearray(b'BASE TABLE')), (bytearray(b'agrupamento_status'), bytearray(b'BASE TABLE')), (bytearray(b'agrupamento_status_personalizado'), bytearray(b'BASE TABLE'))"

Also, if I use de SQLDatabaseToolkit, the 'sql_db_list_tables' doesn't work.
Code:
bedrock_model_id = "anthropic.claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620-v1:0"
llm = ChatBedrock(model_id=bedrock_model_id, client=bedrock_client)
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=database, llm=llm)

agent = create_sql_agent(
    llm=llm,
    toolkit=toolkit,
    prompt=full_prompt,
    verbose=True,
    agent_type="tool-calling",
)

print(agent.invoke({"input": "Give me all the states in the table estado"}))

Result:
Invoking: `sql_db_list_tables` with `{'tool_input': ''}`



Invoking: `sql_db_schema` with `{'table_names': 'estado'}`


Error: table_names {'estado'} not found in database
Invoking: `sql_db_list_tables` with `{'tool_input': ''}`



Invoking: `sql_db_list_tables` with `{'tool_input': ''}`



Invoking: `sql_db_list_tables` with `{'tool_input': ''}`




> Finished chain.
{'input': 'Give me all the states in the table estado', 'output': 'Agent stopped due to max iterations.'}

Does anyone know what the problem could be?
I tried to make my database schema explicit, updated the libraries, but nothing helped.

Well, the error message says it could not find estado table in the database. Either your code connects to the wrong instance / database, or the table does not exist in your database. I don't know whether access rights issue would generate this error. The point is: you need to double check everything

Your table list clearly show there is no table called "estado".  What were you expecting?

maybe use tools like DBeaver to check what you really have in database.
